# Why would Linq2Db not be able to 'see' an Oracle table?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq2db

I have a new account that has read-only access to a new table that our database guy has created. The account can query the table in 'Oracle Sql Developer' but is not the owner of the table (so it doesn't appear in the 'connections' tree) and I think the table is actually a link to another database.

When I save the .tt template file in my C# solution, the class generator runs but doesn't pick up any tables.

When I changed to my normal account, the class generator picks up all the usual tables.

So what are the requirements for Linq2db to see the table? What do I ask the database guy for?

FWIW, this is the query that I'm trying to recreate:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM MySchema.Sectors@STATS
```

and this is my .tt file

```
NamespaceName = "DataModels";
GetSchemaOptions.IncludedSchemas = new []{ "MySchema" };
LoadOracleMetadata(IpAddress, "1521", "DB", "READONLY_ACCOUNT", "password$");
GenerateModel();
```

Comment: Probably because Oracle`s schema is equal to logged user https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37022/223253

Comment: In case anyone finds this, there is no 'fix', we had to manually create our data models, but then they work as normal.